# Copy data from one cell to another when it meets condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through a column of information and if a cell contains data in that column, take data from another column on the same row and then place it into a new cell somewhere else on the sheet, adding it below the last data piece.

```
Sub getLostKeys()

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim kMove As Integer
    Dim cellKeyNum As String
    Dim newCellKeyNum As String
    Dim Kcolumn As String
    Dim Ccolumn As String
    Dim refCell As String
    Dim outputCell As String

    Kcolumn = "K"
    Ccolumn = "C"

    For k = 2 To 301
        If Cells(k, 8) <> "" Then
            cellKeyNum = CStr(k)
            kMove = k + 6
            newCellKeyNum = CStr(kMove)
            refCell = Ccolumn & cellKeyNum
            outputCell = Kcolumn & newCellKeyNum
            Range(outputCell).Value = Range(refCell)
        End If
    Next k

End Sub
```

The code runs and meets the conditional but it doesn't move the cell information to the new cell.

Comment: You are using too many variables. Any reason?

Comment: What does your data look like? I don't *think* you need a macro for this, what are you trying to do? If a cell isn't blank, you just want to put the value in another column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Strings` to set `Cell()` values, you should use `Ranges`.

Try this:

```
Sub getLostKeys()

Dim k       As Integer, kMove as Integer
Dim Kcolumn As Long, Ccolumn As Long
Dim refCell As Range, outputCell As Range

Kcolumn = 11                 ' "K"
Ccolumn = 3                  ' "C"

For k = 2 To 301
    If Cells(k, 8) <> "" Then
        kMove = k + 6
        Set refCell = Cells(k, Ccolumn)
        Set outputCell = Cells(kMove, Kcolumn)
        outputCell.Value = refCell.Value
    End If
Next k

End Sub
```

Note: I've made an assumption or two, so if this errors, or doesn't quite work, it may help to see a sample of the data.

Edit: Also, unless `301` never changes as the last row, you would have a more robust macro if you found the lastRow of column 8, so it's more dynamic and changes if there's say 200 rows, or 4999 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Cells(k, 8) <> "" Then
            kMove = k + 6
            Range("K" & kMove).Value = Range("C" & k).Value
End If
```

should work (remove all those useless variables)

Comment: I managed to work it out, and you're absolutely right. There were many useless variables. Still getting used to some of the syntax/rules in VBA. cheers for the help